# arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion works on layer but not if layer is variable

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, excel

I'd like to loop through a bunch of mxds, on every layers, and from them I'm trying to export excel files. If I use a layer in arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion it works, but as I set a layer as a variable I get an error message. Why? How could I do this instead?

I loop through the layers not the feature classes because I only want to export the visible fields

Here it works as a layer:

```
title = "etwas"
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("mylayername", "C:/TEMP/export_tables/" + title + ".xls", "ALIAS")
```

Here it does not work:

```
inlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("mylayername")
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(inlayer, "C:/TEMP/export_tables/" + title + ".xls", "ALIAS")
```

And here is my error message that I get:

```
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 81, in TableToExcel     raise e ExecuteError:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\TableToExcel.py", line 222, in <module>     arcpy.GetParameter(3))   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Scripts\TableToExcel.py", line 190, in table_to_excel     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, field_names) as cursor: RuntimeError: cannot open 'GPL0'  Failed to execute (TableToExcel).
```

Comment: One issue may be that arcpy.mapping.Layer() specifically expects a lyr file as the input. You need to use tableviews (see @dan's post), makefeaturelayer, or makerasterlayer to create layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since TableToExcel takes an input of Table View data type, I believe you'd have to do something like this:

```
inlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("mylayername")
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(inlayer, "inlayerTableView", "", "", "")
arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("inlayerTableView", "C:/TEMP/export_tables/" + title + ".xls", "ALIAS")
```

Per the documentation, the table view is temporary and will be deleted when the application closes, but if you are looping through layers during one geoprocessing session, you might have to add a counter to increment the table view name in order to avoid a name collision.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-table-view.htm